# Rails Sorting on a value coming from two columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have two tables, A and B. A and B have a foreign key. Both ActiveRecord.

```
class A
  has_one :b
  def valueRendered
    b.value1 || b.value2
  end
end

class B
  ( belongs_to :a, :foreign_key => :keyb ) if self.b
end
```

Here the value coming from valueRendered method in A is having values from field value2 of B when value1 is null. I have to sort the table using the valueRendered, i.e., table should be sorted on the basis of values of both value1 and value2. How to proceed?

> Edit:
>   To be more specific, suppose there is one calculated column (a method in rails) which has value from field "value1" but if value1 is null, the value comes from "value2". I want to sort the whole table (not limited to any specific no of records or scope) with respect to this calculated field (method). I am confused how to proceed.

Some more edit: Actual sample code

> In the controller,

```
  sort_fields = ['offer_orders.id','offers.name','offer_orders.created_at',  
  'offer_orders.country', 'offer_orders.ip_address',       
  'fraud_score_daily.adjusted_fraud_probability, fraud_score_daily.fraud_probability',                    
  'players.email','players.account_status',
  nil,
  nil,
  nil, 
  nil 
  ]

  arel = OfferOrder.includes(:offer, :player, :fraud_score_daily).group('fraud_score_daily.offer_order_id').order('dt desc')
  arel = paginate_table_data(arel, :sort_fields => sort_fields)
```

paginate_table_data method is in a helper

```
def paginate_table_data(arel, opts={})
  opts.assert_keys(:required => [:sort_fields])
  @page_size = page_size
  @current_page = current_page
  arel.paginate(:page => @current_page, :per_page => params[:iDisplayLength]).
  order(order_by(opts[:sort_fields]).join(', '))
end
```

Comment: hi! i dont get what you mean by 'able should be sorted on the basis of values of both value1 and value2'.  did you mean only show A records where their associated B has both values? or order A records based on the B values?

Comment: I have updated the question. See if it clarifies.

Comment: you can't use a method declared in rails in your sql queries.  the closest thing you can implement is what cheeseweasel answered below :)

Comment: That requires it to be declared within the model A but doing so won't help as the order direction (ASC|DESC) is selected at runtime. Moreover the code has already been optimized to have a similar query but doesn't seems to help.

Comment: you can always pass a dynamic order using lambda or class methods.  give the specific code and not some pseudo code so we can understand your requirement.

Comment: @jvnill: updated the ques. Added the relevant code.

Comment: Moreover the first time the data is loaded, it shall be sorted on offer_order_id rather than the values I have discussing about.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this code? and what's wrong with it?  while you're on that, what does `order_by` do?  where does dynamic ordering come in if you're just passing an array of attributes to order?

Comment: Not all of the code can be posted here. The code renders some orders on page using datatables (jquery). The data goes to through the controller. The specific sort field is selected from the UI. "order_by" just implements the same "order" functionality of rails for mysql. Its just that it brings in some dynamic code to include as many no of columns. There is nothing wrong with the code. It is working for all the columns that exist in the table. I just need to add some code fo as to solve the problem I am facing.

Comment: Can you not just add `joins` clauses for any other tables you want to bring in to the `paginate_table_data` method?

Comment: No. The way it has been implemented, joins is not supported. And the code is not limited to be used for this table. There are many other. So making any big change to paginate_table_data won't be possible. The maximum code change is possible only in the controller or the two models, offer_order and fraud_score_daily.

Comment: @cheeseweasel: Did you see my comment below? The one to add a calculated field? Isn't it possible that way?

Comment: You're still going to need to join on the other tables - `includes` would get horrendously inefficient, and I don't see any benefit to using that over `joins`? You could conditionally join based on the table names in the sort fields, but I'm not sure if you're going to run into issues with plurals, and association names here.

Comment: Why do you say joins aren't supported?

Comment: Seems I might have missed on something. Still if join works, how to proceed?

Comment: Okay, just to clarify things, are you saying that it fails for any tables that aren't already in here: `OfferOrder.includes(:offer, :player, :fraud_score_daily)`? If you add the extra associations to the `includes` clause, does it work?

Comment: I added fraud_score_daily. Rest two were already existing in the code. This part works. I just tried out again this way `arel = OfferOrder.includes(:offer, :player).joins(:fraud_score_daily)`. I didn't see any error. Might have done something wrong when I tried earlier.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
scope :order_by_value_rendered, joins(:b).order("value1, value2")
```

Comment: Order is not helping as the asc or desc is selective. I have already tried it.

Comment: sorry, english isn't my first language. what do you mean by `asc or desc is selective`?

Comment: By selective I mean, the order should be ascending or descending is selected at runtime.

Comment: I was thinking while doing the eager load may be if a calculated field is generated which could be used to do the sorting. Is it possible?      I have `arel = A.includes(:b)`. Can anything be done here have a calculated field?